# Can't set parameter for raw SQL in Doctrince

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine

I am using raw SQL in doctrine.
my SQL:

```
   //input datetime type for $dateStart,$dateEnd
    $start = date_format( $dateStart,'Y-m-d');
    $end = date_format( $dateEnd,'Y-m-d');  
       $sql = '
            SELECT 
            *
            FROM 
                    log 
            WHERE 
                    time >= "? 00:00:00" 
            AND 
                    time <= "? 23:59:59"
            ';
        $pdo = $this->em->getConnection();      
        $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bindValue(1,$start);
        $stmt->bindValue(2,$end);       

        $stmt->execute();
        $rs = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

I tried bindValue, bindParam but no hope. I've also tried `$param` as array to pass to `execute` and it did not work.

```
$param = array($start,$end);
```

Could anyone help me?.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[You cannot bind a part of a string literal](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#bindable), but a complete literal only

Besides, it makes no sense to split your date creation between PHP and SQL

```
    $start = date_format( $dateStart,'Y-m-d 00:00:00');
    $end = date_format( $dateEnd,'Y-m-d 23:59:59'); 

    $pdo = $this->em->getConnection();
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM log WHERE time BETWEEN ? AND ?');
    $stmt->execute([$start, $end]);
    $rs = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

Comment: Where you Wrote your Query in Controller / Repository .?

Comment: @Your Common Sense, i am Trying to Write the Script in Repository, can you update your answer with connection string.